# How to Enable Environment Hub

Tags: environment-hub

I would like to know how I can enable Environment Hub in my org. I have been doing research but I did not find much information about it. Am I supposed to contact Salesforce in order for the Environment Hub to be enabled?

Comment: AFAIK, this is a feature for partners on their PBO. I do recommend you contact your account manager or salesforce support.

Comment: I have a Platform Salesforce account, how do I contact my account manager?

Comment: Are you, or do you work for, a Salesforce Partner? If not, you'll need to start the journey through Salesforce Support I guess.

Comment: Fortunately, I could enable the Environment hub in my org. Since I already solved this, I think I can close this question

Comment: It would be normal to post a self-answer, so later people can learn from your experience. If you can spare a few minutes, I would ask you to do that.